# Creating 3 Perfectly Equal Columns that take up 100% on the Browser Window Width

Tags: css

I have 3 square images of the same size that are floating next to each other. I want the three images, in total, to take up the full 100% of the browser window width, with no gaps. Giving each image a width of 33.33333333% works in Firefox, but does not work in most other browsers at certain widths, which can sometimes leave a small gap to the right of the 3rd image.

This may be a problem with many solutions, but nothing I've tried so far works reliably.

Comment: Have you explicitly set border and margin to 0 as well? Also, what about putting the three images into a single file and just displaying that at width:100%?

Comment: Yep, border/margin/padding all set to 0. Can't put them all in one file because I use a media query to display them vertically at mobile window sizes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}

.column {
    width:33.33333333%;
    float:left;
}

.column img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/2p8uk/

Single page demo

http://fiddle.jshell.net/andresilich/2p8uk/show/

CSS3 demo

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    box-orient:horizontal;
    width:100%;
}

.column {
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    box-flex:1;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.column img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/2p8uk/2/

Single page demo

http://fiddle.jshell.net/andresilich/2p8uk/2/show/

---

Update: (safari, sorta, fix)
Safari does not equate 33.33% to 100% like other browsers, you can either use my CSS3 demo, which does the sizing automatically through CSS, or you can encase everything inside a container with a 101% width and just hide that extra 1% with `overflow:hidden;`  off of the third image. Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/image/neptune_voy2.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}

.inner {
    width:101%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.column {
    width:33.33333333%;
    float:left;
}

.column img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/andresilich/2p8uk/4/

Comment: You can see in the jsfiddle (in Safari at least) that it does what I was talking about, with the small gap on the right side. Slowly resize the window width and watch the right side of the 3rd image.

Comment: Actually, the CSS3 demo does seem to work. Very interesting, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: what about `.column { width:33.33%; float:left; } .column:last { width: 33.34%; }` seems like the simple answer to me. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/2p8uk/3/)

Comment: Just tested my first demo in safari and noticed the same, that is due to the size constraint not being fully interpreted by the browser to expand completely, you can fake it thought, check out this demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/andresilich/2p8uk/4/show/

Comment: @rlemon just tried your method but it did not work for me in safari, for some magical reason, it should totally work.

Comment: Setting any of the widths above 33.33 percent causes an overflow in IE. The CSS3 demo almost works, except if you look closely you'll notice that it actually changes the heights slightly, leaving a tiny gap at the bottom of some images.

Comment: @Andreas only problem with the "overflow: hidden" version is that it creates a horizontal scroll-bar.

Comment: @cmal you can hide the overflow by adding 'overflow:hidden' to the container div, and i don't understand whats wrong with the CSS3 demo, how are you applying it?

Answer (score 4):

For those that come here now (oct 2015) you can use calc:

```
width:calc(100% / 3);
```

This will give you exactly 100% when added up. There are some browserbugs but you can use it without many issues: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this...

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div{
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:33.33%;
    background:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/jQA2Z/

**EDIT**

To get rid of that very small space at the right, wrap the `div`s and use a `background-color` or `background-image` to compensate.

```
div#wrapper{
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/jQA2Z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript 33.33% is going to always give you <100% total when added up.

What about 3.5%. Can you afford to lose a pixel or two from the right?

Or put a solid background behind (guessing your answer to this one will be no - but possible)

Answer (score 0):

My work around for this problem has always been as follows:

1. Wrap the 3 columns in a row
2. Have the first 2 columns occupy 33.333333% of the width
3. Finally, select your last column using the last-child filter and apportion a width of 33.333334% (Note that you can apportion the 33.333334% to any of the columns - the first one using first-child filter or second one using the nth-child filter)

Here's the HTML/CSS code

```css
.row {
 width: 100%;
}
.row .cols {
    width: 33.333333%;
    height: 150px;
    float: left; 
}
.row .cols:last-child {
      width: 33.333334%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="cols">lorem</div>
 <div class="cols">lorem</div>
 <div class="cols">lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="cols">lorem</div>
 <div class="cols">lorem</div>
 <div class="cols">lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure any of the above answers are correct, even two years later. This is what I always use to achieve three columns. It requires a couple unique classes, but there is no extra pixels or percentages needed.

HTML:

```
<div id="column-wrapper">
    <div class="column left">
    </div>

    <div class="column mid">
    </div>

    <div class="column right">
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#column-wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
}
.column {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
}
.column.mid {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

This is specifically for a 1000px wide layout, but you can change the math to any layout needed. They key is to make the width of each column a number that when subtracted from the entire width of the div, the resulting number is equally divisible by 2.

For instance, if you wanted to do a 800px wide layout, your columns could be, say, 250px. That means that all three columns added together equal 750px, leaving you with 50px of total space left. So divide 50px by 2 and you get 25px, which is then what you put for your left and right margins on the center column.

Hopefully that makes sense, IMO it is the best and more simple way to achieve three equal columns with pure CSS.