# What makes a perfect 100% width or height having multiple divs together with percentage height/width

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with 100% height and width. The grid is divided in 3 x 3 divs. That means every div has a height and width of 33%.

My question is now what makes the grid perfect looking?

Do I have to use 33.33% for each div that would result in 99.99% or should I use 33.33% for the first 2 rows and the third row has 33.34% to reach 100%?

Or is 33.33333333% for width/height the best?

Comment: A fiddle example may help us to give a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating 3 Perfectly Equal Columns that take up 100% on the Browser Window Width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591343/creating-3-perfectly-equal-columns-that-take-up-100-on-the-browser-window-width)

Comment: maybe you can use `calc()`. for your problem you can calculate like this : 
`#content{ 
   width: calc(100% / 3);
}`

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap utilizes LESS, probably calculates it to be `.col-md-4{width:33.33333333%}`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CSS `calc` function (this must be adjusted for your need, but the idea is to use 100% / 3 )

```
div
{
  width:calc(100% / 3);
  height:calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Comment: The calc function results in 33.33333333% but then I could also use this hardcoded value instead of computing it...