# CSS Styling - Can't centre text in a table

Tags: html, css

```css
.transfers table{
  width: 650px;
  margin: 450px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.transfers tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.transfers th{
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.transfers th, td{
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.transfers .id{
  text-align: left;
}

.transfers .date{
  text-align: center;
}

.transfers .amount{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="transfers">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                    <th class="date">Date</th>
                    <th class="amount">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td style='background-color: blue'>211</td>;
                        <td class='date' style='background-color: blue'>2022-03-29</td>;
                        <td class='amount' style='background-color: blue'>IN: £4.00</td>;
                        </tr>;
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am currently trying to make it so ID is on the left side, date is in the centre and amount is on the right side:

However, as you can see from the image below using the CSS code above, the spacing between "Date" and "Amount" is large. Date is clearly not in the centre.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue including the related html

Comment: Preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, done now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the table that is not centered. Your columns appear with different widths. You could insert width for the largest or all columns to equally distribute the space.

```css
.transfers table{
  width: 650px;
  margin: 450px auto;
  }

.transfers .id{
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.333333%;
}

.transfers .date {
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.333333%;
}

.transfers .amount {
  text-align: right;
  width: 33.333333%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="transfers">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="id">ID</th>
            <th class="date">Date</th>
            <th class="amount">Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style='background-color: blue'>211</td>;
        <td class='date' style='background-color: blue'>2022-03-29</td>;
        <td class='amount' style='background-color: blue'>IN: £4.00</td>;
        </tr>;
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

For more options, you'll find some methods which will help you in  [Creating 3 Perfectly Equal Columns that take up 100% on the Browser Window Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591343/creating-3-perfectly-equal-columns-that-take-up-100-on-the-browser-window-width)

Answer (score 1):

Set for all columns the same width.

```css
.transfers table {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.transfers tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.transfers th {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.transfers th, td {
  text-align: center;
  /* border: none; */
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}

.transfers .id {
  text-align: left;
}

.transfers .date{
 
}

.transfers .amount{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
    <div class="transfers">
        <table border>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                    <th class="date">Date</th>
                    <th class="amount">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>                
              <tr>
                <td class="id">211</td>
                <td class='date' >2022-03-29</td>
                <td class='amount' >IN: £4.00</td>
              </tr>                  
              <tr>
                <td class="id">211</td>
                <td class='date' >2022-03-29</td>
                <td class='amount' >IN: £4.00</td>
              </tr>                     
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.transfers table{
  width: 651px;
  margin: 450px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.transfers tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.transfers th{
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.transfers th, td{
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.transfers .id{
  text-align: left;
}

.transfers .date{
  text-align: center;
}

.transfers .amount{
  text-align: right;
}
td{width:217px;}
```

```html
<div class="transfers">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                    <th class="date">Date</th>
                    <th class="amount">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td style='background-color: blue'>211</td>;
                        <td class='date' style='background-color: blue'>2022-03-29</td>;
                        <td class='amount' style='background-color: blue'>IN: £4.00</td>;
                        </tr>;
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```